# Proper way to restrict member value to subset of set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Say I have a person object with a field that is profession, which is simply a list of strings.  What is the canonical way, using Spring and hibernate, to restrict this list to only a subset of professions that are defined by either user or the admin?  Ie, the list of global, predefined professions at runtime is {Accountant, Developer}, and the user adds 'Plumber' to the list.  Now if a new person is created, I'd like to restrict the possible professions that person can have to the 3 that are in the list.

Originally, I implemented an Enum, but this seems like a poor design, as it's generated at compile time, and can't be added to at run time (I think?).  Would the proper way be to define a one column table with profession, and at each request to make a person, populate a singleton with one member, which is a list of the professions?  Then the domain object person would only source the profession from the singleton (presumably in the service layer?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Entity Profession which is related to Person with a one-to-many relationship. This way a profession is always only what is persisted by Hibernate. The profession entity does not need much. Just an id and name for now. Later you might add more attributes as you need.

Comment: Ah ok, was curious if this is the proper way.  I guess I can't get over the fact that the java-side implementation is coupled with the hibernate design.  I keep envisioning a standalone java app which is only backed by a database.  Not the case here, since hibernate is restricting the values of Profession, which without hibernate (the database), wouldn't be done.  So, would the Profession member of Person just be List<Person> and get populated via the service layer?

Comment: Possibly. You could make a uni-directional relationship where the Profession does not know about the Person. But its up to you.